# How to add shadow to CircularNetworkImageView

Tags: java, android, android-volley

How to add border to CircularNetworkImageView and control width and color of border? 
Dont notice icons around image)

Like this:
[image]

```
public class CircularNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    Context mContext;
    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        if(bm==null) return;
        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),
                getCircularBitmap(bm)));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a circular bitmap and uses whichever dimension is smaller to determine the width
     * <br/>Also constrains the circle to the leftmost part of the image
     *
     * @param bitmap
     * @return bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        if(bitmap.getWidth()>bitmap.getHeight())
            width = bitmap.getHeight();
        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, width);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = width / 2;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, paintBorder);
paintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
```

In your code, it could look like this:

```
public class CircularNetworkImageView extends NetworkImageView {
    Context mContext;
    Paint mPaintBorder;
    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);
    }
    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        init(context);
    }

    public CircularNetworkImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs,
                                    int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init(context);
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        mPaintBorder = new Paint();
        this.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mPaintBorder);
        mPaintBorder.setShadowLayer(4.0f, 0.0f, 2.0f, Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        if(bm==null) return;
        setImageDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(mContext.getResources(),
                getCircularBitmap(bm)));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a circular bitmap and uses whichever dimension is smaller to determine the width
     * <br/>Also constrains the circle to the leftmost part of the image
     *
     * @param bitmap
     * @return bitmap
     */
    public Bitmap getCircularBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
                bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        int width = bitmap.getWidth();
        if(bitmap.getWidth()>bitmap.getHeight())
            width = bitmap.getHeight();
        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, width);
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = width / 2;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, mPaintBorder);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
}
```

Though I really hate that you create all those objects inside `getCircularBitmap`. It would be much better practice IMHO to make your other `Paint` object a field and initialise it inside the new `init` method.